# Polymorphism with jQuery UI Widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, inheritance, widget

I'm looking at using inheritance with jQuery UI widgets to help simplify some code I'm working on. However, I have the need to be able to operate on the base widget type, even though it was the inherited type that was initialised.

So, for example, let's say that a widget `bar` inherited from a widget `foo`, and I initialised an object like so:

```
$('.something').bar();
```

At times I'll need to be able to do this:

```
$('.something').foo('someMethod');
```

I haven't been able to get something like this to work so far.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing.  I've found a solution discussed here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/widget-inheritance-no-polymorphism (from 2010!) but haven't tried it for myself yet.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this problem personally, I have written a plugin that will allow you to call a widget method without knowing what *type* the widget is.  This will allow you to do:

```
$('.something').callWidgetMethod('someMethod', 'arg1', 'arg2');
```

It allows you to do things like 'disable' all widgets on the page (for example):

```
$('*').callWidgetMethod('disable');
```

It relies on you using jQuery UI 1.11+.  If you are using <1.11, you can take out the *"Skip this widget if it does not have the method"* check, but the downside of that is that you will get an error if you attempt to call a method that the widget does not have.

**Plugin code**:

```
jQuery.fn.callWidgetMethod = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    var result = null;
    if(!this || !this.length) 
        return this;

    this.each(function (i,o) {
        var compClass = $(this).data("widgetName");
        var func = $(this)[compClass];
        // Skip this element if it does not appear to be an initialised jQuery widget
        if(!compClass || !func)
            return true;

        // Skip this widget if it does not have the method (the name of which will be in args[0])
        // This relies on the 'instance' method provided in jQuery UI 1.11
        if(args.length>1 && !$(this)[compClass]("instance")[args[0]])
            return true;

        result = func.apply($(this),args);
    });

    if(this.length>1) 
        return this;
    else 
        return result;
};
```